# How to check the data in readonly field using selenium webdriver or javascript

Tags: selenium

There are 4 read only text box.

I need to check whether the read only text box has values or not?

How to do it in selenium webdriver?

Comment: There will certain properties of the text box which will help you find out if the text box is readonly. Please share the html. Will let you know how to handle the scenario.

Comment: <input id="txtPatinetLastName" class="ReadOnlyStyle" type="text" style="width:100%;" readonly="readonly" value="BENTON" name="txtPatinetLastName"> ----- this is the html code... Thanks for ur comment

Comment: This is my code,I tried this" String text = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPatinetLastName")).getText(); "

Comment: Thanks for the details. Could you edit your question to include this? It's much easier to to find it in the question properly formatted than to have it posted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ruby method to check the data of elements :

```
def assert_element_text(message, css_path_to_the_element)
  wait.until { assert_equal(message, element_by_css(css_path_to_the_element).text) }
end
```

The `element_by_css` method is using this selenium methods :

```
def find_element(method, value)
  driver.find_element(method, value)
end

def _element_by(method, args)
  return wait.until { find_element(method.gsub(/element_by_/,'').to_sym, args[0]) }
end
```

`wait` methods are only there to make sure selenium is waiting for elements before trying to access them

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Getting the Locator for the Read Only Text Box:txtPatinetLastName is the ID for the Text Box.

Step 2:

Checking the Data:

Store the existing data

String actualdata=driver.findElement(By.id("txtPatinetLastName")).getText() 
String expecteddata=".....";

if(!actualdata.equals(expecteddata))

FAIL;

else

PASS;

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element using id & then fetch the data using get attribute, something like
String elementval = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPatinetLastName")).getAttribute("value");

Now elementval variable contains the value "BENTON".